# Multiple Custom Cells in TableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Fairly new at this. I'm trying to populate 3 custom cells into a TableViewController.

I've managed (with help) to get 2 to load with no trouble. This is the code i use for 2:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell") as! FirstTableViewCell
        cell.artImageView.image = UIImage(named: "art")

        return cell

    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell") as! SecondTableViewCell
        cell.kidsImageView.image = UIImage(named: "kids")


        return cell
    }
```

When I try to add a third row, this is where I run into trouble. This is the code i'm using:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row % 3 == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell") as! FirstTableViewCell
        cell.artImageView.image = UIImage(named: "art")

        return cell

    } else if {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell") as! SecondTableViewCell
        cell.kidsImageView.image = UIImage(named: "kids")


        return cell

    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ThirdCell") as! ThirdTableViewCell
        cell.pastaImageView.image = UIImage(named: "pasta")


        return cell
    }

}
```

Any help would be great. Gracias.

Comment: You didn't specify the condition in second if else statement: `} else if {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue starts with this line

```
  if indexPath.row % 3 == 0 {
```

If you really want the cells to be laid out 1,2,3 you can just do this:

```
 if indexPath.row  == 0 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell") as! FirstTableViewCell
    cell.artImageView.image = UIImage(named: "art")

    return cell

} else if indexPath.row == 1 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell") as! SecondTableViewCell
    cell.kidsImageView.image = UIImage(named: "kids")


    return cell

} else if indexPath.row == 2 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ThirdCell") as! ThirdTableViewCell
    cell.pastaImageView.image = UIImage(named: "pasta")


    return cell
}
```

using `indexPath.row % 3 == 0` is doing modulus math so it is giving you the "FirstCell" only when indexPath.row/3 is equal to an integer. Then you have an `else if` that has no test so it is getting called for all other rows. Finally your `else` never gets called.

Comment: Thanks @Walter, this seems way more straight forward! I'm getting an error though, it's saying "Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'. Not sure why

Comment: The LAST line needs to be a return. So, you can either rearrange the braces or just put return UITableViewCell() as the last line in the func. Because you have all of the returns above, it will never get to the last line, but the compiler isn't smart enough to know that.

Comment: Make the last `else if` an `else`, and remove the condition.